# Parse form textarea by comma or new line

Tags: php

I have a textarea in a form that allows users to enter a list of numbers separated by either a newline or a comma. I need the numbers they entered to be entered into an array. Unfortunately, the code I have does not work all the time. If users enter comma sepated data and a newline then the comma is left in the resulting array. In addition, if they add a newline at the end of the textfield then it enters an empty value into the array. The code I have is below:

```
$data = preg_split( "[\r\n]", $_POST[ 'textarea' ] );
if (count($data) == 1) {
    $string = $data[0];
    $data = explode(',', $string);
}
```

I was hoping for some help on how to get around the issues I am having.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"a list of numbers separated by either a newline or a comma"
So, you do not care which one it is, or if there is a comma *and* a newline? Then why not simply use all three characters equally as separators and allow "one or more" of them?

```
<?php
$input = '1,2,3
4,5,,,,
,6,
7
,8,9';

$data = preg_split("/[\r\n,]+/", $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($data);
```

prints

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "7"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "9"
}
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you! I will look up the extra parts of preg_split you have put in so that I fully understand what you have done.

Comment: what a nice solution, prost mein Freund!

Comment: I would also add space (\s) to the regular expression so that spaces before and after the number are removed. It would look like `[\r\n,\s]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$input = '1,2,3
4,5,,,,
,6,
7
,8,9
';

$data = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), ',', $input);
$data = array_filter(explode(',', $data));

var_dump(array_values($data));
```

prints

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "7"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "9"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons could be that you are missing delimiter and `+` to find one ore more, instead of this:

```
$data = preg_split( "[\r\n]", $_POST[ 'textarea' ] );
```

Try:

```
$data = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", $_POST[ 'textarea' ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should "trim" the user input from white space:

```
$data = preg_split("[\r\n"], trim($_POST["textarea"]));
```

This will remove leading and trailing white space. You can also remove leading and trailing commas - to prevent empty array indices when csv is used - by specifying a comma as second argument to trim:

```
trim($data, ",");
```

For more info on trim see http://php.net/trim

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = preg_split( "/[\r\n]+|,/", trim($_POST['textarea']) );
```

This will split by either newlines or commas, and eliminate any trailing newlines.

Comment: I have tried your code but, unfortunately, it is not splitting the form data correctly if there are both commas and newlines. For example, if a user inputs:

3, (newline here)
4, (newline here)
4, (newline here)
6

Then it cannot handle it. I would like to sort this out server side if possible.

Comment: What I mean to say is that it separates twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip also multispaces to single spaces, trim spaces before and after, and allow also for semicolon ';' instead of just comma ',', then this code worked for me. I'm confident this could be done in a single preg_split and/or preg_replace though!

```
$string = '  1,2,3
   4,5,;,,
   ;6,
7
,   8   ,9; 10  ; 11;';

$tmp = preg_split("/[\r\n,;]+/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach($tmp as $val)
{
    $val = trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $val));
    if($val != "")
        $data[] = $val;
}

var_dump($data);
/* Returns
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "7"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "9"
  [9]=>
  string(2) "10"
  [10]=>
  string(2) "11"
}
*/
```