# how to separate data pasted from excel to textarea

Tags: php, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse form textarea by comma or new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483216/parse-form-textarea-by-comma-or-new-line)

I am copying data from a single column in excel and pasting it in textarea

On submit i need to get data pasted from excel in a array

> $data=explode('\n',$_POST['url']);

or

> $data=explode('\t',$_POST['url']);

doesn't work

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to check this question:
[Parse form textarea by comma or new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483216/parse-form-textarea-by-comma-or-new-line)

using that in your code:

```
 <?php

 if(isset($_POST['url']))
 {


 $input = $_POST['url']; 

 $data = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
 var_dump($data);



 }

?>
```

$data array will have the required data